# Why is my unique ID posts after refresh browser (React, MongoDB, Express, Node)?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, key, mern

I am rather new to React and am making an app with the MERN stack to create, read, update and delete recipes but I'm getting the warning from React that I don't have a unique key for my recipe items. However, when I refresh my browser the warning goes away and my recipe object now has the id. It looks like the recipe ID is not being posted until after the recipe items are re-rendered. I don't get the warning if I pass the index as the key but I am just really wanting to understand why I keep getting this error when trying to use the ID generated from MongoDB.

````
class RecipeContiner extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: "",
            ingredients: "",
            summary: "",
            recipes: []
        }

    }
    //GET RECIPES
    componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:5000/recipes/';

        axios.get(url)
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({ recipes: res.data })
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    onChangeHandler = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    }

    //POST RECIPE
    onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const recipe = {
            title: this.state.title,
            ingredients: this.state.ingredients,
            summary: this.state.summary
        }

        const url = 'http://localhost:5000/recipes/add';

        axios.post(url, recipe)
            .then(res => console.log('new recipe!', res.data));

        this.setState({
            recipes: [...this.state.recipes, recipe],
        });

        e.target.reset();

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler}>
                    <label>Title:</label>
                            <input type="text" onChange={this.onChangeHandler} name="title"/>
                    <label>Ingredients:</label>
                            <input type="text" onChange={this.onChangeHandler} name="ingredients"/>
                    <label>Summary:</label>
                            <input type="text" onChange={this.onChangeHandler} name="summary"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
                <RecipeList recipes={this.state.recipes} />
                <Fab color="primary" aria-label="add">
                    <AddIcon />
                </Fab>

            </div>
        );
    }


//RECIPE LIST COMPONENT
const RecipeList = (props) => {
    console.log('props.recipes', props.recipes)
    const recipes = props.recipes;
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {recipes.map((recipe, index) => (
                    <RecipeItem
                        key={recipe._id}
                        title={recipe.title}
                        ingredients={recipe.ingredients}
                        summary={recipe.summary}
                    />
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );

}

//RECIPE ITEM COMPONENT
const RecipeItem = (props) => {
    return (
            <li>
                <div>{props.title}</div>
                <div>{props.ingredients}</div>
                <div>{props.summary}</div>
            </li>
    )
}
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZtEO.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your state don't get the id after you post id. you just add the new recipe from the client and not form the server with the id.

```
  axios.post(url, recipe)
        .then(res => this.setState({
        recipes: [...this.state.recipes, res.data],
    } ,()=>console.log('new recipe!', res.data)));
```

will do the trick.